# Input and output a set of character with an array by using getchar() and putchar()

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, character, getchar

I am newbie to the world of C programming language and not so familiar with the function putchar() and getchar().I try to write a code that read a set of character inputted and store it in an array.
Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100

int main(){
    int i;
    char c[MAX_SIZE]={0};
    printf("Enter message:");

    for(i=0;getchar()!='\n';i++){
        c[i] = getchar();    /*looks like some error here that the compiler didn't found out.....*/
    }

    for(i=0;c[i]!='\n';i++){
        putchar(c[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program runs successfully but didn't work well. The result outputted is chaotic and totally have no meaning.
I wonder what's wrong with my code as it looks no error for me(so does the compiler seen correct to it). I wish i can get an explanation besides getting a correct way to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead use the following

```
int value;

for ( i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE && ( value = getchar() ) != EOF && value != '\n'; i++ )
{
    c[i] = value;
}

for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++ )
{
    putchar( c[j] );
}

putchar( '\n' );
```

Otherwise at least in this loop

```
for(i=0;getchar()!='\n';i++){
        ^^^^^^^^
```

you are skipping each even character

And the header `<ctype.h>` may be removed because neither declaration from the header is used in the program.

Comment: So does that even means that getchar() will read the next character every times that i used no matter where? It this the only way to write it?

Comment: @Grasshelicopter Yes, getchar will read the next character if you will not even assign its result.